# Is it a good practice to put a colon (:) at the end of step definition for cucumber dataTable?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumberjs, jbehave, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have seen in many examples that it is not required to put a colon at the end of (Given|When|Then) step definitions where cucumber data table is specified. What if a colon is specified similar to Jbehave syntax ? Is it error prone?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gherkin has no rules about this, so it's down to whatever convention works for you. FWIW I do this for data tables and doc strings.